# Select Max Distinct Dates from list of Dates

Tags: sql, rapidsql

I have a table which is a list of dates with times. For example

Dates

```
1/3/2014 6:16:43.570 AM
1/3/2014 6:17:02.300 AM
1/3/2014 6:23:09.700 AM
1/6/2014 6:02:09.993 AM
1/6/2014 6:02:34.323 AM
1/6/2014 6:03:02.957 AM
1/6/2014 6:08:48.867 AM
1/6/2014 6:09:04.917 AM
```

What I want to end up with is:

```
1/3/2014 6:23:09.700 AM
1/6/2014 6:09:04.917 AM
```

since those are the most recent times for each date.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT MAX(datetime)
FROM Dates
GROUP BY DATE(datetime)
```

Comment: So I assume that datetime is the column name of the column that has all of the dates, and "Dates" is the table name. However, I am getting the error that DATE is not a built in function name. I am using Embarcadero Rapid SQL 7.6.4 if that is important.

Comment: Yes, that is important. My answer is for MySQL. `DATE` takes a datetime and returns the date part of it. You'll have to find the equivalent function in your DBMS, I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Please tag your question for Rapid SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by or row number.  Here is row number to show you another way to do it. (Since others have shown the group by example)

```
SELECT d
FROM
(
   SELECT d,
          row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY convert(date,d) ORDER BY d DESC) as rownum
   FROM Dates
) t
WHERE rownum = 1
```